# Implementing perror() - issue

Tags: c, posix

I'm implementing the `perror()` equivalent to an API that I'm using.

The perror() ISO C std [`doc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/perror.html) says:

> The perror() function shall not change the orientation of the standard
>   error stream.

but programmatically, what it means?

I'm using `fprintf(stderr, .. )` currently. Is a mistake use it? if true, why? if is there some error in my implementation(see below), points for me please.

Check out my C code based on my interpretation:

```
void
fooapi_perror(const char *s)
{
  char *emsg;

  if(s != NULL && *s != '\0')
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: ", s);

  emsg = fooapi_strerror(GetLastErrorCode()); 
  fprintf(stderr, "%s\n",  emsg); 
  free(emsg);
}
```

Comment: Interesting, your link is to the POSIX standard, not the ISO C standard.  My copy of ISO/IEC 9899:1999 is almost identical to the one you linked to - except the line you are querying!

Comment: You might like to modify the title of your question from the quiet general wording `... perror() - issue` to a more specific one like `... perror(): output stream orientation`, as it's more about the latter then about the `perror()` implementation itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each C stream has a property - "orientation" either "wide-oriented" or "byte-oriented" which is determined by the first operation on this steam. You are allowed to alter the orientation of a steam when the stream doesn't have an "orientation".Calling any function whose orientation conflicts with the orientation of the stream results in undefined behavior.

For example, printf would have the steam becoming a byte-oriented while the wprintf cause the steam being a wide-oriented.

As far as your question is concerned, perror should not change the orientation of its stream.

So in your code, if the stream the perror using have already had an orientation, you should make sure that you are not calling a function whose orientation conflicts with the current orientation of the stream.

Answer (score 4):

You can determine the orientation of the stream with [`fwide(3)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/fwide.html), and use that to decide whether to call `fprintf` or `fwprintf`.

```
void
fooapi_perror(const char *s)
{
    const char *emsg = fooapi_strerror(fooapi_geterrcode());

    if (fwide(stderr, 0) <= 0) {
        // byte-oriented or not yet oriented
        if (s && *s)
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", s, emsg);
        else
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", emsg);
    } else {
        // wide-oriented
        if (s && *s)
            fwprintf(stderr, L"%s: %s\n", s, emsg);
        else
            fwprintf(stderr, L"%s\n", emsg);
    }

    free(emsg);
}
```

Note: this doesn't conform to the "does not change the stream orientation" requirement when the stream has not yet acquired an orientation, because there is no way to *un*-orient a stream, nor is there any way to send output to a stream without giving it an orientation.  [The GNU libc implementation of `perror`](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdio-common/perror.c) resorts to a dirty hack in this case (duplicating the underlying file descriptor!)  Perhaps we should just chalk it up under "standard C wide character support is not really fit for purpose anyway" and move on.

Tangential kibitz: `fooapi_strerror` should return a pointer to a string constant, not a pointer that has to be `free`d.